# MailKit 3.4.2 - "535: 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful"

Tags: authentication, email, smtpclient, mailkit

I am trying to send mail to a client's Exchange server that uses NTLM authentication and am getting a *"535: 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful"* error when using port 587 and on port 465 I get this error *"An error occurred while attempting to establish an SSL or TLS connection."*

My development environment .Net 4.7.2

The code am using is below

```
 // Add Content to Mime Message
                var bodyBuider = new BodyBuilder();
                message.Subject = subject;
                bodyBuider.HtmlBody = body;
                message.Body = bodyBuider.ToMessageBody();

                #endregion

                #region Send Mail

                SmtpClient cli = new SmtpClient();

                try
                {
                    // mitigate signed exchange server certificate by an unknown certificate authority
                    cli.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;


                    cli.Connect(emailServerInfo.Host, emailServerInfo.Port, SecureSocketOptions.Auto);

                    // If username and Password is supplied
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailServerInfo.UserName) == false)
                    {
                        if (cli.AuthenticationMechanisms.Contains("NTLM"))
                        {
                            var ntlm = new SaslMechanismNtlm(emailServerInfo.UserName, emailServerInfo.Password);
                            cli.Authenticate(ntlm);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cli.Authenticate(emailServerInfo.UserName, emailServerInfo.Password);
                        }
                    }

                    cli.Send(message);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    this._audit.AddError(new Shared.Models.Audit.AuditErrorAddRequestInfo(ex));
                    ret.Add(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    cli.Disconnect(true);
                }
                #endregion
```

I think this code should work because I tried it with a Sendgrid and the email gets sent. I appreciate any help I can get

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to disable SSL certificate revocation checks.

```
// mitigate signed exchange server certificate by an unknown certificate authority
cli.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;
cli.CheckCertificateRevocation = false;
```

Comment: Thanks, @jstedfast. Tried that but didn't work and still getting the same errors